# Check contain numbers/digits

Tags: c#, .net, contains

I'm quite new to C# visual studio. I wanted to ask if it's possible to use the contain function to check if my program contains numbers/digits in a DataTable row?

p/s: I've tried the regex function (referring to some topics discussed online)

```
string checkstring = "1234567890";
Regex reNum = new Regex(@"^\d+$");
bool isNumeric = reNum.Match(checkstring).Success;

for (int i = 0; i < my_datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    data_source = my_datatable.Rows[i][4].ToString();

    if (data_source.Contains(reNum.Match))
    {
        my_datatable.Rows[i][4] = "Contain Number";
    }
    else
    {
        my_datatable.Rows[d][4] = "No number";
    }
}
```

But it seems it doesn't work at all, is there any other method? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: So you want to check whether the cell contains number or contains only number?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the cell contains only digits, you need to use your regex within the `for` loop.

Instead of

```
if (data_source.Contains(reNum.Match))
```

Use

```
if (reNum.Match(data_source))
```

This will return true if `data_source` is only digits (note - only works for positive integers - you need a different strategy if you have other characters like a leading dash or decimal points or commas).

If you want to test for the presence of any digits (but other characters are also ok) then you will want to change your regex string to just be `@"\d"` which will return true if there is at least one digit present.

Comment: Noted, i will try this solution, thanks for your reply @vorkosigan

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < my_datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string data_source = my_datatable.Rows[i][4].ToString();
    if (data_source.Any(x=>Char.IsDigit(x)))
    {
        my_datatable.Rows[i][4] = "Contain Number";
    }
    else
    {
        my_datatable.Rows[i][4] = "No number";
    }
}
```

Where `data_source.Any(x=>Char.IsDigit(x))` will check whether the `data_source` contains at lease one digit, if so replace the cell text to `"Contain Number"` else the cell text would be `"No number"`. If you want to change the condition to check for all numbers replace `Any` with `All()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if there's *any* integer numbers (e.g. "**-123456**") in the 4th column you can try combining *Linq* and *regular expressions*:

```
  var hasNumbers = my_datatable
    .Rows
    .OfType<DataRow>()
    .Where(row => row[4] != null)
    .Any(row => Regex.IsMatch(row[4].ToString(), "^-?[0-9]+$"));
```

If you want to check that 4th column contains digits e.g. "bla-bla-**7**-bla":

```
  var hasDigits = my_datatable
    .Rows
    .OfType<DataRow>()
    .Where(row => row[4] != null)
    .Any(row => row[4].ToString().Any(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'));
```